# Scrolling inside the tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, containers, subview

I have a static table view that all of its rows is fit in a view controller (no scrolling is needed).

I also have a subview that I want to add it in the last row, since this subview is tall, it should be scrolled. 
I did these things but none of them works:

1- I added a `scrollView` in the last row and I have set constraints to fit it in the last row. Then I define it as an outlet and add the subview to it in `viewdidload`. The subview is added but the scrolling doesn't work

2- I add a container in the last row, and I also add the `scrollView` to on the subview and I have set constraints to fit it in the subview, then I added this subview that contains `scrollView` to the container, but the scrolling doesn't work.

Could help me to do that? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably just forgetting to set the scroll view's content size:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let theView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: ...))
    scrollView.addSubview(theView)
    scrollView.contentSize = theView.frame.size
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, It works perfectly now. I can thank you enough